# ggplot2 adding dynamic arrow annotations pointing at specific data points that remain proportional to the scale of the overall plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, stock, arrows

I would like to create a template that would allow me to create a line graph of stock prices with the ability to add arrows pointing at specific dates. The annotation function on ggplot2 does not allow for resizing with the scale of the plot. Is there any workaround?

For example, in this plot with only 6 dates the arrows are sized properly with the chart:

```
prices<-c(3,5,28,17,62,10)
prices2<-prices-1
prices3<-prices-11
dates<-seq.Date(from=as.Date("2018-1-1"),to=as.Date("2018-1-6"),"days")

ggplot()+
geom_line(aes(dates,prices))+
annotate(
"segment",
x=dates,
xend=dates,
y=prices3,
yend=prices2,
color="blue",
arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.5,"cm")
            ))
```

[image]

However when I increase the period to 15 dates the arrows do not scale proportionally and look like this:

[image]

Comment: My first thought would be to try using a relative unit like `npc` instead of `cm` when specifying the arrow length.

Comment: how did you generate prices3 and prices2?

Comment: They are just a random series that I made up. `prices<-c(3,5,28,17,62,10)`

Comment: npc looks better but still doesn't produce arrows of proportional size. This is the code for df: `prices<-c(3,5,28,17,62,10)
prices2<-prices-1
prices3<-prices-11
dates<-seq.Date(from=as.Date("2018-1-1"),to=as.Date("2018-1-6"),"days")`

Comment: Yeah, the arrow head size is a separate thing (in that it isn't directly controlled by the length argument). I've seen several question here on SO with people fussing over how to size them correctly. If you look you may find something useful, but my impression has been that it's a pain.

Comment: A further complication is when I convert the line chart to a log scale which further throws off the placement of the arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by proportional, is it essentially same proportional length to the first figure? If so, since the length of the arrow is controlled by `prices2` and `prices3` you can just figure out how much space they take proportionally on the first figure and then compute for the second. Combine with `npc` for arrow head and it should roughly give you what you want. The arrowhead itself isn't perfect because of the x-axis but I think it's closer than what you had before.

So using your data:

```
# original data
prices<-c(3,5,28,17,62,10)
dates<-seq.Date(from=as.Date("2018-1-1"),to=as.Date("2018-1-6"),"days")

# original plot (with 0.05 npc)
ggplot()+
    geom_line(aes(dates,prices))+
    annotate(
        "segment",
        x=dates,
        xend=dates,
        y=prices-11,
        yend=prices-1,
        color="blue",
        arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.05,"npc")
        ))
```

[image]

```
# new data
prices2<-c(prices,c(20,250,30,60,40))
dates2 <- seq.Date(from=as.Date("2018-1-1"),to=as.Date("2018-1-11"),"days")

# compute length of arrow
p1 <- abs(min(prices)-11)+max(prices)
fs1<-function(x) { (abs(min(prices2)-x)+max(prices2))*11/p1-x }
y1<-uniroot(fs2,lower=0,upper=100)$root

p2 <- abs(min(prices)-1)+max(prices)
fs2<-function(x) { (abs(min(prices2)-x)+max(prices2))*1/p2-x }
y2<-uniroot(fs1,lower=0,upper=100)$root

# new plot
ggplot()+
geom_line(aes(dates2,prices2))+
annotate(
    "segment",
    x=dates2,
    xend=dates2,
    y=prices2-y1,
    yend=prices2-y2,
    color="blue",
    arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.05,"npc")
    ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think I figured out a similar idea:
`prices2<-prices-(max(prices)/100)*2
prices3<-prices-(max(prices)/100)*8`
which sets the arrows to the minimum and maximum value and sets the length to to some predetermined graph of that goes from 0 - 100.
But what would you do if you are plotting on a logarithmic basis?

Comment: transform your data before you plot it instead of using `scale_y_log10()` then apply the same principles

Comment: `ggplot()+
     geom_line(aes(dates,log(prices)))+
     annotate(
         "segment",
         x=dates,
         xend=dates,
         y=log(prices)-max(log(prices))/100*8,
         yend=log(prices)-max(log(prices))/100*2,
         color="blue",
         arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.03,"npc")
         ))`

Comment: Thanks, that works but then the Y axis is not labeled properly. What I need is the annotation to size itself relative to the graph size and not according to the data. Another solution would be formula that adjusts the size on a logarithmic basis.